# Organic Search Segment in Google Analaytics API for Apps Script

Tags: javascript, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get all organic entrances for a single URI. I filtered for ga:pagepath==uri and tried to use the segment ga:organicSearches. However the segment doesn't seem to work! I get the following error: "Invalid value 'ga:organicSearches' for segment parameter" Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is my funtion:

```
function getEntrancesForUri(uri) {

  var endDate = '2016-01-26';
  var startDate = '2015-12-28';

  var profileId = xxxxxxxx;
  var tableId = 'ga:' + profileId;


  var optArgs = {
    'filters': 'ga:pagePath=='+uri,
    'segment': 'ga:organicSearches'
  };

  var result = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
    tableId,
    startDate,
    endDate,
    'ga:entrances',
    optArgs
  );

  if (result) {
    return result;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how you construct a segment. Also ga:organicSearches is a metric, and you probably want to segment by a dimension.

You can use a [dynamic segment as described here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/segments#users-vs-sessions) which would probably look like this:

> sessions::condition::ga:medium==organic

This segments out sessions that have arrived via an organic search.

Alternatively you can create your segment in the GA interface and find the segment id via the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/), and use that in your query. Testing your queries in the Query Explorer is a good idea in any case, since you get instant feedback and sometimes even a useful error message.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The code works now. Strangely I still don't get the right values!  The values delivered from the function differ slightly from the values I get directly from google analytics when filtering for organic entrances.

Comment: I rather suspect that the API works in a different timezone than the interface (so the start/end for selected sessions differs). I get differences in smaller timeframes, too, and they are smoothed out the longer the selected timeframe is. I do not know what can be done about this.

Comment: Fyi: I noticed a little error in your answer. The correct solution would be: "sessions::condition::ga:medium==organic"